# Makefile: Last appended text not recognized

Tags: makefile

I created a build system which uses Makefiles in each subdirectory (except for the `include` directories and its subdirectories). The current directory tree looks as follows:

```
src/
├── arch
│   └── x86
│       ├── boot
│       └── include
│           ├── asm
│           └── uapi
│               └── asm
├── core
├── drivers
│   ├── block
│   ├── char
│   ├── screen
│   └── stream
├── fs
├── include
│   ├── drivers
│   ├── elfboot
│   │   └── debug
│   ├── fs
│   └── uapi
│       └── elfboot
└── mm
```

Each Makefile contains information about the target to be build as well as relevant subdirectories:

**./src/Makefile:**

```
elfboot-d += arch
elfboot-d += core
elfboot-d += drivers
elfboot-d += mm
elfboot-d += fs
```

The target is `elfboot`, the `d` tells the build system that all directories listed belong to the target `elfboot`. Files are appended to the target via, e.g.:

**./src/drivers/block/Makefile:**

```
elfboot-y += ata.o
elfboot-y += ramdisk.o
elfboot-y += scsi.o
```

Files can be part of several different targets, you only have to add a line with the name of the other target followed by a `-y`. I provided a minimal working example below:

**./Makefile:**

```
srctree  := .
objtree  := .

define collect_target
objtree := $$(objtree)/$(1)
srctree := $$(srctree)/$(1)
btarget := $$($(2)-d)

$(2)-y  :=
$(2)-d  :=

include $$(srctree)/Makefile

$(2)-objs += $$(patsubst %,$$(objtree)/%,$$($(2)-y))

$$(foreach subdir,$$($(2)-d),$$(eval $$(call collect_target,$$(subdir),$(2))))

$(info $($(2)-y))

srctree := $$(patsubst %/$(1),%,$$(srctree))
objtree := $$(patsubst %/$(1),%,$$(objtree))
endef

$(eval $(call collect_target,src,elfboot))

all: $(elfboot-objs) $(bootstrap-objs)
    @echo "Finally done!"
```

However, typing

```
$ make
```

gives me this output:

```
console.o core.o device.o errno.o printf.o screen.o string.o

ata.o ramdisk.o scsi.o
tty.o
vga.o
random.o
memblock.o page_alloc.o slub.o util.o
make: *** No rule to make target 'fs.o', needed by 'all'.  Stop.
```

When I swap the last two lines in the Makefile at `./src/Makefile` (first `fs`, then `mm`), the output changes to:

```
console.o core.o device.o errno.o printf.o screen.o string.o

ata.o ramdisk.o scsi.o
tty.o
vga.o
random.o
fs.o ext2.o isofs.o ramfs.o super.o
make: *** No rule to make target 'memblock.o', needed by 'all'.  Stop.
```

Why does this happen? What is the problem with the last line of this specific Makefile? It just seems that the last `elfboot-d` text that is appended to the variable is not stored or recognized. What is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: You almost certainly want to defer your `info` in the define block as well, else it isn't really giving you the results you want: `$$(info $$($2-y))`

Comment: It's a little hard to envision what is happening here.  I recommend you use the standard eval debug method and just before you run an `eval` you place an `info` which has the same arguments: that will print out the makefile block that make is about to evaluate.  So: `$(info $(call collect_target,src,elfboot)) $(eval $(call collect_target,src,elfboot))` and ditto (with `$$(info ...`) inside the loop in the defined variable.  Maybe that output will give you some ideas what is happening.

Comment: @MadScientist that was actually the reason, I must have been blind.